# SSIS SQL Command datetime parameter with timezone offset

Tags: ssis, timezone, offset

I am designing a SSIS package to transform data from SQL DB to another SQL DB. I'm using OLE DB source and have Query written as SQL Command. I'm passing a datetime parameter which will be read via SSIS variable from XML configuration file. In Config file I'm setting date as '2/16/2011 2:00:00 AM'. This parameter is being used in the query from SQL Command to get the data inserted/updated after given date. When I run the SSIS package I'm not getting correct data. To dig this further, I had run SQL Profiler to check the value of the parameter being sent and noticed that whenever the SQL Command query is being called, it is suffixing offset (-08:00) to the parameter. Is there any way to not to set the offset when SSIS runs?

Comment: What is the Data Type of your SSIS variable, and of your destination column?

Answer (score 0):

When I set up an OLEDB source and use it to query a datetime field in a table, it returns the correct values.

eg: select FULLDATETIME from  where FULLDATETIME = '12/5/2010 02:00:00 AM'

I get the following result:

2010-12-05 02:00:00

Sounds like you could be querying a datetimeoffset field. You'll need to adjust your literal value with dateadd(), eg select dateadd(mi, datediff(MI, getutcdate(),GETDATE()), '2/16/2011 2:00:00 AM')